# How to use logging unicode in python 2.6?

Tags: python

I have a simple logging handler:

```
log = logging.getLogger()
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(ch)
```

command:

```
log.error(unicode('тест'))
```

result:

```
UnicodeDecodeError
```

How to logging unicode message ?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with 2.6 or logging but just that you're calling `unicode` on an encoded string.

```
>>> unicode('тест')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Specifying an encoding or passing a unicode string to logging works fine.

```
>>> log.error(unicode('тест', encoding='utf-8'))
ERROR - тест
>>> log.error(u'тест')
ERROR - тест
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
log.error(u'тест')
```

Calling `unicode` on a string literal with encoded content is not what you want; just specify to python that it's a unicode literal and it should work.

**Even better:** If you're using unicode literals through your program, I would just do:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

at the top of all your source files, and then not worry about it at all:

```
log.error('тест')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure whether it will be enough, but if the error is `UnicodeDecodeError`, it means that it happens while trying to convert raw characters to unicode.

In your code, it should happen in :

```
unicode('тест')
```

You should try instead :

```
unicode('тест',  charset)
```

where `charset` is your current charset

You could try too :

```
unicode(u'тест')
```

with directly a unicode constant.